# frequency of characters and letter pairs (python)

Tags: python-3.x

I need to obtain the frequency of characters and the letter pairs in a file that I'm ingesting and cleaning.

The current code ingests the file, cleans the text and removes all whitespace. The latter part of the code outputs the frequency of characters, but in a multidimensional_list, which isn't the desired output.

I haven't been able to figure out how to obtain letter pairs.

For example:  my text has items that have multiple letters in sequence.
aa aaaa oooo zzz ssss, etc.  I need to obtain these combinations.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and assistance solving these issues.

```
from collections import Counter

new_words = []
with open ('words.txt', 'r') as infile:
lines = [line for line in infile.readlines() if line.strip()]
for line in lines:
    clean_line = re.sub(r'(\b(section\s[\d]{1,2})\b)', '', line)
    clean_line_2 = re.sub(r'([()])', '', clean_line)
    new_words.append(clean_line_2.lower().replace('.', '').replace(';', '').replace('\n', '').replace('-', ' ').replace(" ", ""))


if len(new_words) > 0:
for item in new_words:
    print (Counter(item))


**outout:**

Counter({'a': 8, 'l': 3, 'i': 2, 'h': 2, 'z': 1, 'j': 1, 'n': 1, 's': 1, 'r': 1, 'u': 1, 'w': 1, 'f': 1, 't': 1})
Counter({'a': 14, 'n': 4, 'e': 4, 'i': 3, 'h': 3, 'l': 3, 'w': 2, 'd': 2, 'o': 2, 'f': 2, 'r': 1, 't': 1, 's': 1, 'y': 1, 'k': 1, 'u': 1, 'j': 1})
Counter({'a': 15, 'b': 6, 'i': 6, 'h': 4, 'w': 3, 'n': 3, 'f': 2, 's': 2, 'r': 2, 'k': 2, 't': 2, 'm': 1, 'd': 1, 'g': 1, ',': 1, 'u': 1})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correclty understood this question, you need one Counter for all the charactes and another for pair of characters.

```
import re
from collections import Counter


new_words = []
with open('words.txt', 'r') as infile:
    lines = [line for line in infile.readlines() if line.strip()]

for line in lines:
    clean_line = re.sub(r'(\b(section\s[\d]{1,2})\b)', '', line)
    clean_line_2 = re.sub(r'([()])', '', clean_line)
    new_words.append(clean_line_2.lower().replace('.', '').replace(';', '').replace('\n', '').replace('-', ' ').replace(" ", ""))
```

Join all the lines to count total frequency in the file:

```
new_words_unit = ''.join(new_words)

if len(new_words_unit) > 0:
    print (Counter(new_words_unit))

Out:  # smth like this 
Counter({'a': 8, 'l': 3, 'i': 2, 'h': 2, 'z': 1, 'j': 1, ...})
```

Now define `chunk` function to group characters into pairs and count them:

```
def chunk(iterable, size=2):
    length = len(iterable) - 1  # stop before reaching last character
    result = []
    for i in range(length):
        result.append(iterable[i:i+size])
    return result

size = 2
new_words_pairs = chunk(new_words_unit, size)  # chunk string
new_words_pairs = [''.join(i) for i in new_words_pairs if len(i) == size]  # filter single chars

print(Counter(new_words_pairs))

Out:  
Counter({'aa': 'ao': 1, 'dd': 2, 'df': 1, 'dr': 1, ...})
```

Note: all those pairs interset each other. I.e. `'abcc' -> 'ab', 'bc', 'cc'`

Comment: WOW!! Will the latter work on patterns, such as 'aaa' or 'zzzz?

Comment: Nope. But if you describe required output with examples, I can modify it to do so, I guess :) Something like input - output simple pairs

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yesterday was a travel day with lots of delays.

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works great.  I will try to modified it to take the parameters (input, number).

Comment: Glad to hear it! Guess changing a value of the`size` argument in the `chunk` function can help. Also the set of poerators `+ - | &` defined for a `Counter`, so you can group all the counters if it's necessery (docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 0):

For the second part:

```
from itertools import groupby
my_counts=[(key, len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby(new_words)]
```

That should give you count for each unique item in the list

Comment: This looks like it gives me the unique sentences in my multidimensional_list, but not the individual characters.  THANKS for this code example, because I needed it too!

Comment: Please share desired output